# Where is fromRealFrac?

Tags: haskell

Where can I find the `fromRealFrac` function? According to [the gentle intro](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) the function should exist and from a bit of googling around, I gather it should be in Prelude - yet ghci complains that it's not in scope.

I'm using `fromRational . toRational` for the time being, as according to the gentle intro that's how `fromRealFrac` is meant to be defined.

Comment: My guess is that this function was (re)moved post-Haskell 98.

Comment: That's most likely a typo in the gentle intro.  You want `realToFrac`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function formerly known as "fromRealFrac" was renamed "realToFrac" in the Haskell 98 Report.

In the [Haskell 1.4 Prelude](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/haskell/haskell-report-1.4-html/standard-prelude.html) we find

```
fromRealFrac    :: (RealFrac a, Fractional b) => a -> b
fromRealFrac    =  fromRational . toRational
```

However, by [Haskell 98](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) it is known as

```
realToFrac     :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
realToFrac      =  fromRational . toRational
```

This change is listed in the [Haskell 98 Report Errata](http://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell98-bugs.html):

```
[Apr 2001] Page 84, Section 6.4, Fig 7; and bottom of page 86, Section 6.4.6.
    fromRealFrac :: (RealFrac a, Fractional b) => a -> b
should be replaced by
    realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

The closest commit I could find was [this](http://darcs.haskell.org/haskell98-report/_darcs/patches/20010405162240-c7106-02f284591dfa05c798c836b5985ce974d06a1cdd.gz) in the report repo.

Comment: I wonder why nobody cares to fix the "gentle intro" on the official haskell website.

Answer (score 5):

[It appears](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2001-February/006575.html) this function is called [`realToFrac`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3arealToFrac) in the GHC Prelude.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), there is [no function named `fromRealFrac`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fromRealFrac) in the standard libraries. <strike>Perhaps it is a function that the authors of the gentle intro made up themselves?</strike>After looking at the link, they certainly suggest that it is in a library somewhere...I'm confused, too.